# How do I upload files to Object Storage on Bluemix using Cyberduck or ExpanDrive?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, cyberduck

I'm on a mac and struggling to upload large files to Bluemix's Object Storage.  My credentials don't look like what is in [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/1b48459f-4091-43cb-bca4-37863606d989?lang=en) tutorial:

```
{
"auth_url": "https://identity.open.softlayer.com",
"project": "object_storage_xxxxxxxx",
"projectId": "xxxxxxxx",
"region": "dallas",
"userId": "xxxxxxxx",
"username": "member_xxxxxxxx",
"password": "xxxxxxxx",
"domainId": "xxxxxxxx",
"domainName": "xxxxxxxx",
"role": "member"
}
```

Has anyone had any luck uploading files on a mac?

Answer (score 1):

I would download the profile from the link suggested by David above and modify the content as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Protocol</key>
        <string>swift</string>
        <key>Vendor</key>
        <string>cyberduck</string>
        <key>Context</key>
        <string>/v3/auth/tokens</string>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string>Openstack Swift (Keystone 3)</string>
        <key>Username Placeholder</key>
        <string>Project Name:Project Domain:Username</string>
        <key>Password Placeholder</key>
        <string>Password</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Fill out the server, port, Project Name:Project Domain:Username and Password. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To connect with Cyberduck, install the [Openstack Swift (Keystone 3) profile](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/bluemix).